# How can I take a screen cap behind a JFrame?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm using `Robot.createScreenCapture(...)` to capture an area of the users screen but I don't want the user to be able to see a certain JDialog within the resulting image. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using ```setVisible(false) -> take picture -> setVisible(true)``` ?

Comment: I have but I was hoping for a more elegant solution because you have to setvisible(false), what till next frame, take the image, setVisible(true) which  isn't very smooth, the operation is done in a loop so the user would also see the dialog flickering

Comment: If it happens in a loop, couldn't you ```setVisible(false)``` for the duration of the loop? Wouldn't that get rid of the flickering?

Comment: i get some very strange behaviors, the box is mainly invisible and appears every once in a while for a couple of ms then vanishes.